# Chrome Node in Selenium/Docker keeps crashing

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have a CentOs virtual machine running a selenium chrome node in docker

```
Static hostname: btpcentos1.kaiglan.com
Icon name: computer-vm
Chassis: vm
Virtualization: vmware
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64
```

Every time it try to execute a test against it i receive this error:

```
Capabilities [{message=unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426924       (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64  x86_64), platform=ANY}]Session ID: ada09670c280a5327585e930a27c067d at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteTimeouts.setScriptTimeout(RemoteWebDriver.java:829)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringTimeouts.setScriptTimeout(EventFiringWebDriver.java:564)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ConfigureTimeout.call(ConfigureTimeout.java:52)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ConfigureTimeout.call(ConfigureTimeout.java:27)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  11:59:22.693 WARN - Exception: no such session
```

I use the following command to start the node:

```
docker run -d -p 5556:5556 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null-e SE_OPTS="-host IP -port 5556" -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=IP -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444 -e SCREEN_WIDTH=1920 -e SCREEN_HEIGHT=1080 --name Node2 selenium/node-chrome:3.0.1-aluminum
```

Any ideas on why chrome keeps crashing ?

Comment: It looks like the VM needs more RAM.

Comment: You can try with Zalenium: https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/blob/master/docs/usage_examples.md#install-and-start

Comment: @flowfree the linux box has 6GB of ram

Comment: it looks like you need a space between /dev/null and -e SE_OPTS